# 3 Servers, 2 Work Fine, One Has Network Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, nic, bonding

i have 3 servers, all relatively the same hardware/config, etc. I run some data pulls on all 3, and on 2 of them, they have 1 nic, and they work fine. On the other , there are 2 nics, and unless they are both plugged in or teamed, the processes time out.

Any ideas on why this would be? It doesn't make sense to me, as the other two work fine with 1 nic and don't time out when running the same processes.

Comment: that sounds like wrong routing issue where it would use the other network card not reaching the destination and timing out

Answer (score 0):

Could be a routing issue - if you only plug in one of the two network cards, are the routes set so they all go via the one, connected network card? If not, that's likely to be your problem.